# Is recreating an existing logo as vector a copyright issue?

Tags: vector, logo, copyright

A company I've been working for has lost the vector versions of their logo. They've asked if I could recreate them, copying the jpeg version they have exactly to provide vector files. The logo is basically just Rockwell Bold in a coloured square so it would be very simple to do.

If I obliged, would I be infringing copyright, as I didn't design the original? I'm unsure, as I would not be copying to make something new, but just to replace the files that went missing (i.e. were presumably copied over).

I guess the alternative is to suggest they contact their original designer first, and if they can't help, would that then be acceptable for me to do so?

Comment: The company should own the copyright. if they do not they have bigger problems.

Answer (score 4):

They should attempt to contact the original designer first, although he/she may not have (or ever had!) a vector version.

If not, there should be no reason you couldn't be hired to re-create their logo as vector; I've done it many times for clients.

As @joojaa mentioned above, if someone other than the company owns the copyright to their logo, they have bigger problems. But even then, I don't know that there'd be an issue, as you are not trying to use the logo commercially anyway, nor are you trying to copy/reuse any part of it for a different logo.

Comment: Exactly. I don't see any problems here. As long as they own the copyright to their own logo, then having you translate it from raster to vector so they can use it in other media is no different from having you place the logo in a Word document so they can use it on internal stationery.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, great to know and very reassuring. Have a great weekend